# Who has more related friends in FB

Tags: algorithm, mongodb, facebook-graph-api, graph, neo4j

I'm developing one application, that will have multiple Facebook users.

I'm trying to figure out the best way of knowing who (from a list of up to about 20), has most connections (friends) with others from that list.

So, let's say this situation:

`list = [A, B, C, D, E, F...];`

where, `A` is friend of `B`, `C` and `D`. And `B` is friend of `A` and `C`.

I would then know, that `A` has 3 connections, `B` has 2, and `C` has 2. And use `A` as the one to post something.

I thought in some solutions:

1) For every person in the list, check for friend connection of all others (using Graph API).

2) Cache all friends of all users, in the DB (maybe `Neo4j` or `MongoDB`, `SQL`...), and then transverse the search, looking for common friends.

Problem of 1: Might take time to do it every time.
Problem of 2: DB will grow really big.

Question: Is 1 and/or 2 ok? Is there any other way of doing it? (I read the Facebook API, but didn't saw anything like this).

Comment: B can be a friend of B himself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Neo4j as you stated. Save persons in neo4j including their relationships (Friendships) and then use query similar to this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[f:FRIENDS]-(b:Person)
WHERE Id(a) IN [1, 2, 3] AND Id(b) IN [1, 2, 3]
RETURN a.name AS name, count(f) AS numOfFriends
ORDER BY numOfFriends DESC
```

Comment: Should I use the Neo4j then?

Comment: Neo4j is graph database and is meant to handle relationships between nodes (like firendship in your case). My opinion is that neo4j is more appropriate than SQL or MongoDb.

Comment: Nice. Also, should I consider using other DB for Password/user data storing, and so on? Or if it fit's Neo4j, should I adapt the ideas to it?

Comment: It depends what kind/how much data you want to store about user. But generaly, I wouldn't use neo4j for that. You want to keep history of user data (which value is correct for a particular moment in time i.e. user changes Shipping address, and you want to keep the old address). I would use SQL for that.

Comment: You can store password/user in Neo4j as well if you want to or other data. Only binary is not well suited.

Comment: One more question: Can I use MongoDB to do that sort of query?